# How to unassign courses of Students in Student-Course relationship table without deleting data from database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing database of Course-Result Management System. One of the story is:

**Unassign all courses taken by the students by a button click**

I designed three tables based on the story. The schema is,

**Students( StudentId, StudentName, RegNo )**

**Courses( CourseId, CourseCode, CourseName )**

**Enroll( StudentId, CourseId, EnrollDate )**

At first I thought I could create a copy of Enroll table named *Enroll_BCK* and insert data in both *Enroll* and *Enroll_BCK* at the same time by one button click from the application. But that required deleting the *Enroll* table and other hassle.

Is that a good approach?

How do I clear the *Enroll* table for next semester students without actually deleting data from database?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: The way to do it would actually be to delete from the enroll table.  Why are you hesitant to do that?

Comment: It's because of the specification. It says, _you cannot delete data from database for unassigning courses_ . I am also unsure that if I scale up then it would make performance issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a column (could also be datetime for deletion history)

```
ALTER TABLE Enroll ADD isDeleted bit DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

You need to put logic in your procedures, functions and queries to account for this.

Then when "deleting" you update this column to 1.

```
UPDATE Enroll SET isDeleted = 1 -- You may want to add a WHERE clause
```

Otherwise you could copy the content of the table to a clone table with a different name like this:

```
SELECT * INTO Enroll2016 FROM Enroll
DELETE Enroll
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will try both of these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a many-to-many relationship in your database like you have between students and courses, it requires an intermediate table like the one that you have: `Enroll`.  In order to indicate that a particular student is taking a particular course, you would insert a record into the `Enroll` table.  The way you would remove the mapping between students is to delete the record.

I'm not sure why you are uncomfortable with deleting records from the `Enroll` table, but that is how it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My specification said not to delete data from database. If that line was not added, then I would definitely delete record from _Enroll_ table,